# Pyspark Dataframe Apply function to two columns

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql

Say I have two PySpark DataFrames `df1` and `df2`.

```
df1=   'a' 
        1    
        2    
        5    

df2=   'b'
        3
        6
```

And I want to find the closest `df2['b']` value for each `df1['a']`, and add the closest values as a new column in `df1`.

In other words, for each value `x` in `df1['a']`, I want to find a `y` that achieves `min(abx(x-y))` for all `y in df2['b']`(note: can assume that there is only one `y` that can achieve the minimum distance), and the result would be

```
'a'    'b'
 1      3
 2      3
 5      6
```

I tried the following code to create a distance matrix first (before finding the values achieving the minimum distance):

```
from pyspark.sql.types import IntegerType
from pyspark.sql.functions import udf

def dict(x,y):
    return abs(x-y)
udf_dict = udf(dict, IntegerType())

sql_sc = SQLContext(sc)
udf_dict(df1.a, df2.b)
```

which gives

```
Column<PythonUDF#dist(a,b)>
```

Then I tried

```
sql_sc.CreateDataFrame(udf_dict(df1.a, df2.b))
```

which runs forever without giving error/output.

My questions are:

1. As I'm new to Spark, is my way to construct the output DataFrame efficient? (My way would be creating a distance matrix for all the `a` and `b` values first, and then find the `min` one)
2. What's wrong with the last line of my code and how to fix it?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Starting with your second question - you can apply udf only to existing dataframe, I think you were thinking for something like this:

```
>>> df1.join(df2).withColumn('distance', udf_dict(df1.a, df2.b)).show()
+---+---+--------+
|  a|  b|distance|
+---+---+--------+
|  1|  3|       2|
|  1|  6|       5|
|  2|  3|       1|
|  2|  6|       4|
|  5|  3|       2|
|  5|  6|       1|
+---+---+--------+
```

But there is a more efficient way to apply this distance, by using internal `abs`:

```
>>> from pyspark.sql.functions import abs
>>> df1.join(df2).withColumn('distance', abs(df1.a -df2.b))
```

Then you can find matching numbers by calculating:

```
>>> distances = df1.join(df2).withColumn('distance', abs(df1.a -df2.b))
>>> min_distances = distances.groupBy('a').agg(min('distance').alias('distance'))
>>> distances.join(min_distances, ['a', 'distance']).select('a', 'b').show()
+---+---+                                                                       
|  a|  b|
+---+---+
|  5|  6|
|  1|  3|
|  2|  3|
+---+---+
```