# How to create a new shapely points column in PySpark dataframe using lat and lon

Tags: python, dataframe, apache-spark, pyspark, shapely

I have a use case, where the data look something like this

```
TS     |    Lat   | Lon 
____________________________
1      |    20.2  |   78.3 
2      |    20.3  |   78.4
3      |    20.4  |   78.4
4      |    20.5  |   78.4
5      |    20.6  |   78.4
```

I'm using pyspark dataframes, no scope to use pandas because of performance issues on larger dataframes. I'm looking for a solution in pyspark.

I want output something like this, creating a column containing shapely POINTS.

```
from shapely.geometry import Point

TS     |    Lat   | Lon      |  Point
__________________________________________________
1      |    20.2  |   78.3   | Point (20.2 ,78.3) 
2      |    20.3  |   78.4   | Point (20.3 ,78.4)
3      |    20.4  |   78.4   | Point (20.4 ,78.5)
4      |    20.5  |   78.4   | Point (20.5 ,78.6)
5      |    20.6  |   78.4   | Point (20.6 ,78.7)
```

How to do this ? Kindly help

Comment: Have a look at [Spark UDFs](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/pyspark.sql/api/pyspark.sql.functions.udf.html) or [Pandas UDFs](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/pyspark.sql/api/pyspark.sql.functions.pandas_udf.html), they should do the job. But I suggest you to think about whether you can use shapely Points directly from a pyspark dataframe or not.

Answer (score 1):

Spark does not natively support geospatial data types (ref: https://www.databricks.com/blog/2019/12/05/processing-geospatial-data-at-scale-with-databricks.html)

But you can store geospatial data as a wkt string type. For example:

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql.types import StringType
from shapely.geometry import Point, LineString, Polygon

spark = SparkSession.builder.getOrCreate()

df = spark.read.parquet(path)
point_udf = udf(lambda x,y: Point(x,y).wkt, returnType=StringType())
df = df.withColumn('wkt', point_udf(df.x, df.y))
```

Alternatively, Apache Sedona integrates with spark and enables geospatial operations to be performed using cluster computing. Using Sedona a point geometry type column can be created:

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql.types import StringType
from shapely.geometry import Point, LineString, Polygon

spark = SparkSession.builder.getOrCreate()

from sedona.register import SedonaRegistrator

SedonaRegistrator.registerAll(spark)

df = spark.read.parquet(path)
df.createOrReplaceTempView("df")
df_with_geom = spark.sql("Select x, y, ST_Point(x,y) AS geometry from df")
```

You can confirm that a geometry type has been created by checking the schema

```
df_with_geom.schema
```

Answer (score 0):

Building on top of @*Mariusz*'s answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40390422/16120011):

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import udf
from shapely.geometry import Point

def to_point(lon, lat):
    return Point(lon, lat)

udf_p = udf(to_point)

df = df.withColumn("Point", udf_p(df["Lon"], df["Lat"]))
```

Comment: Tried this method, but for me an error appearing something like this, Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: net.razorvine.pickle.objects.ClassDict.__setstateCaused by: net.razorvine.pickle.PickleException: failed to __setstate__() _Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: net.razorvine.pickle.objects.ClassDict.__setstate__([B)

Comment: Error is too big, can't copy the whole thing here

Comment: Can you try with `return {"type": "Point", "coordinates": [lon, lat]}` ?

Answer (score 0):

Sedona also directly supports loading shapely points. See here: https://sedona.apache.org/latest-snapshot/tutorial/geopandas-shapely/#interoperate-with-shapely-objects

```
from pyspark.sql.types import IntegerType, StructField, StructType

from sedona.sql.types import GeometryType

schema = StructType(
    [
        StructField("id", IntegerType(), False),
        StructField("geom", GeometryType(), False)
    ]
)

from shapely.geometry import Point

data = [
    [1, Point(21.0, 52.0)],
    [1, Point(23.0, 42.0)],
    [1, Point(26.0, 32.0)]
]


gdf = spark.createDataFrame(
    data,
    schema
)

gdf.show()
```

Install Sedona on EMR: https://sedona.apache.org/latest-snapshot/setup/emr/

Install Sedona on Databricks: https://sedona.apache.org/latest-snapshot/setup/databricks/#install-sedona-via-init-script-for-dbrs-73

Runnable Sedona Python examples on MyBinder: https://sedona.apache.org/latest-snapshot/tutorial/jupyter-notebook/